# RedirectToAction - but I want it to go to http://example.com/controller/action/id?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, redirecttoaction

I'd like to move an asp.net mvc response to

http://example.com/emails/list/rob@email.com

Using RedirectToAction("list", "emails", new { id = "rob@email.com"}); takes you to http://example.com/emails/list?id=rob@email.com.

What am I doing wrong?

Thanks,

Rob

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seems like misconfigured routing. Your RegisterRoutes method in Global.asax.cs should look like this:

```
    public static void RegisterRoutes(RouteCollection routes)
    {
        routes.IgnoreRoute("{resource}.axd/{*pathInfo}");

        routes.MapRoute(
            "Default",                                              // Route name
            "{controller}/{action}/{id}",                           // URL with parameters
            new { controller = "Account", action = "Login", id = "" }  // Parameter defaults
        );

    }
```

In line "{controller}/{action}/{id}" presence of **{id}** means that is going to be substituted by it's value.
Any other parameter that is not present in routing string would be decoded as ?some_param=value

Answer (score 0):

Ah - because the default route requires 'id', your parameters in the view (html) and the controller must be called id.